# Anrede bei Brief/E-Mail an mehrere Personen, wobei man mit machen per du, mit manchen per Sie ist

Tags: style, politeness

Angenommen man schreibt eine E-Mail oder einen Brief an mehrere Personen, bei denen man mit manchen per Du ist, und mit anderen per Sie. Was wäre dann die empfohlene Anrede?

Ich hatte z.B. vor kurzem den konkreten Fall, dass ich eine E-Mail an ein Team geschrieben habe, bei dem ich zwar mit allen fünf Mitgliedern per du bin und engen Kontakt habe, aber seit neustem auch ein Vorgesetzter im Team ist, mit dem ich per Sie bin.

Eine Mischung aus Sie und Du finde ich sehr verkrampft. Da ich mit der Mehrheit per Du war, habe ich mich entschieden, in der Anrede "Liebe Kollegen" zu verwenden, und im Text habe ich dann immer im Plural gesprochen, etwa "Was haltet ihr von meinem Vorschlag?". Unterschrieben habe ich nur mit Vornamen.

Meine Frage ist nun, was es in diesem Fall bzw. allgemein in einer entsprechenden Situation für ein Stil angemessen ist, bzw. von was es ggf. noch abhängt.

Meine Frage bezieht sich nicht nur auf die Anrede am Anfang, sondern, auch im Text (du, sie, ihr) und wie man unterschreibt, voller Name, Vorname...

Comment: Deine Lösung mit `Liebe Kollegen, ...` ist bei mehr als drei Personen sehr gut. Das ganze hängt sehr von der Zusammensetzung des Teams ab. Ein lockeres `Hallo ...`ist da manchmal fehl am Platz.

Comment: @help-info.de: Meine Frage bezieht sich nicht nur auf die Anrede am Anfang, sondern, auch im Text (du, sie, ihr) und wie man unterschreibt, voller Name, Vorname...

Comment: Obwohl die Fragestellerin ausdrücklich präzisiert hat, dass es um die Verwendung von Du, Sie oder Ihr im Text und um die Unterschrift geht, wird die Frage als Duplikat zu einer älteren Frage geschlossen, die ausdrücklich "Was wäre eine gute Anrede?" lautete und deren Antworten sich auch nur darauf beziehen. Ich habe die Präzisierung in die Frage kopiert und hoffe, sie wird wieder geöfnet.

Comment: Wenn Du "Sie" großschreibst, solltest Du auch "Du" großschreiben (auch i.d. Überschrift).

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn ich mich recht erinnere musste man nach der alten Rechtschreibung das Pronomen "du" immer groß schreiben. [Heute](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/du) sind beide Varianten erlaubt. Meist liest man es klein, aber manche Leute finden es in Briefen und E-Mails persönlicher oder höflicher, es groß zu schreiben. "Sie" hingegen wird als Pronomen [immer](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sie_Anrede) groß geschrieben (dein "wenn dann" Satz suggeriert ein bisschen, dass das nicht so sei).

Comment: @userunknown, das förmliche Anredepronomen *Sie* (und seine Formen *Ihr* und *Ihnen*) wird **immer** großgeschrieben! Die persönlichen Anredepronomen *du* (*dir*, *dich*, *dein*) und *ihr* (*euch*, *euer*) werden seit 1996 in der Regel kleingeschrieben, können aber in Briefen, E-Mails, etc. weiterhin großgeschrieben werden. Kurzum, das Prinzip Alles-oder-Nichts gilt hier nicht. Siehe etwa https://gfds.de/du-dich-dein-dir-gross-oder-kleinschreibung-bei-den-anredepronomen/#

Comment: @Julia: Erlaubt ist vieles, wenn man nicht dem Notendruck eines Deutschlehrers ausgesetzt sitzt. In Briefen und E-Mails sprichst Du mit Du/Sie jemanden direkt an. Hier aber reflektierst Du über Wörter und deren Verwendung ("per Du sein, per Sie sein") und sprichst niemanden mit Du/Sie an. Welcher lateinische Begriff "per Du sein" nun am akkuratesten trifft ist mir zwar unbekannt, aber offenbar ist die Wortart des Du und Sie hier die gleiche, also müssen sie sich den gleichen Regeln beugen. Du schreibst das eine groß, das andere klein und mal auch beides groß ...

Comment: ... - stilistisch beißt sich das. Hättest Du nur eins benutzt hätte ich geschwiegen. Ich lehne die neuen Regeln persönlich auch als inkonsistent ab, aber würde ohne Disklaimer natürlich niemandem hier empfehlen es nach Rechtschreibrat falsch zu machen. :) Aber wenn beide zusammen auftreten müssen sie meines Erachtens gleich geschrieben werden. Alles andere sieht wie Kritik an der Sprachreform aus. ;)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Du und Sie werden hier von Julia aber nicht als Anrede benutzt, sondern sie schreibt über Sprache, also reflexiv. Dabei mal das eine groß, mal klein zu schreiben und direkt neben dem großgeschriebenen Sie verletzt mein ästhetisches Empfinden und meinen Sinn für Logik und Ordnung. Dein gfds-Link behandelt "per Du/Sie sein" gar nicht.

Answer (score 5):

Dazu wird es vermutlich verschiedene Meinungen, geben, es spielen meiner Ansicht nach auch die Art des Betriebs, regionale Eigenarten, vielleicht das Alter der Leute im Team etc. eine Rolle.

Hier in Nordbaden, wo ich wohne, ist es zum Beispiel im Beruf oft üblich, "Ihr" als Plural von "Sie" zu benutzen ("Hallo Frau Meier! Sagen Sie mal, habt Ihr in der Bachstraße noch Kardanmuffen am Lager?"), aber im Hochdeutschen ist das natürlich falsch, der Plural von "Sie" ist "Sie".

Wenn man eine Gruppe also mit "ihr" anspricht, hat man sie eigentlich geduzt, und die klassische Regel ist eigentlich, dass man eine Gruppe, in der die Anreden für die einzelnen Personen gemischt ist, immer siezen müsste, weil das die höflichere Form ist. Das gälte erst recht, wenn die formal "wichtigste" angesprochene Person gesiezt wird. Demnach gäbe es da eigentlich nur die Optionen, entweder zu siezen oder immer beides anzugeben ("Was halten Sie / haltet ihr von dem Vorschlag?"). Die Form mit beidem finde ich auch sehr verkrampft, bei der Form mit Sie besteht die Gefahr, dass die langjährigen Kollegen sich vielleicht (zwar eigentlich zu Unrecht, aber trotzdem) übergangen fühlen.

Ich würde es, wie du vermutlich in deiner Mail, auch davon abhängig machen, was im Betrieb sonst üblich ist. Wenn sich alle duzen und der neue Vorgesetzte eigentlich nur deshalb noch nicht geduzt wird, weil er noch neu ist und man noch kein Duzen vereinbart hat, oder wenn das Team insgesamt jung und nicht sehr konservativ ist, würde ich es genauso wie du machen, auch wenn das nicht den klassischen Regeln entspricht.

Wenn abzusehen ist, dass der Vorgesetzte auch in Zukunft gesiezt wird, oder wenn die Firmenkultur allgemein konservativ ist, würde ich siezen oder versuchen, die Situation zu vermeiden. Vielleicht ist es im Einzelfall eine Möglichkeit, die Mail formal nur an einen direkten Ansprechpartner (m/w/d) für das Thema innerhalb des Teams zu addressieren (den man dann duzen oder siezen kann) und das Team in CC zu nehmen mit einer Formulierung wie "Vielleicht kannst du ja mit dem Team besprechen, was Ihr davon haltet". Hängt natürlich davon ab, was im Betrieb üblich ist und ob es so einen Ansprechpartner gibt.